# How to set attribute for id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Html part

```
<input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
<input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
<input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
<input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
<input type="text" class="demo" id="" value="" />
```

My Jquery part

```
$( ".demo" ).attr( "id", "sample_1" );
```

However,am getting same id for all the inputs.

Now i want to increment the id as sample_2, sample_3...for n number of input's.

How, can I do it???

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a function to `attr` instead of a static value:

```
$('.demo').attr('id', function (i) {
    return 'sample_' + (i + 1);
});
```

Comment: there is a bracket missing

Comment: @user3271762 - `return 'sample_' + (i + 4)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/WG68C/4/)

```
    $( ".demo" ).each(function(index, el){

$(this).attr( "id", "sample_"+(index+1) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this should help

```
var idNumber=-1;
$('.demo').each(function(){
idNumber+=1;
$(this).attr("id",idNumber);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do ya!

```
<script type="text/javascript">

setTimeout(function () {

    var inputs = document.body.querySelectorAll('inputs[type="text"]');

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        inputs[i].id = 'sample_' + (i + 1);
    };

}, 100);
```

```
<input type="text" class="demo" />
<input type="text" class="demo" />
<input type="text" class="demo" />
<input type="text" class="demo" />
<input type="text" class="demo" />
```